# Ruby file output issue

Tags: ruby, text, output

I have written some ruby to automate batch file creation, the problem lies with the resulting output in the GUI;

[image]

The files are outputted, but the formatting looks very strange indeed. Also the filenames are all ending in '.txt' but MacOS does not see it this way. i.e. You cannot click to open in Textedit.

Code is as follows;

```
puts "Please enter amount of files to create: "
file_count = gets.to_i
puts "Thanks! Enter a filename header: "
file_head = gets
puts "And a suffix?"
suffix = gets
puts "Please input your target directory:"
Dir.chdir(gets.chomp)


while file_count != 0
  filename = "#{file_head}_#{file_count}#{suffix}"
  File.open(filename, "w") {|x| x.write("This is #{filename}.")}
  file_count -= 1
end
```

Tips on shortening length or refactoring are always welcome.

Comment: None of your posted code is in any way related to your GUI image. Please update your question.

Comment: The GUI above is the output location specified when running the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) documentation contains:

> The separator is included with the contents of each record.

By default the separator is a newline (see [`$/`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/globals_rdoc.html)). So both `file_head` and `suffix` end with a newline character. `filename` also does, of course. Thus the extension of your files isn't `.txt` as it's actually `".txt\n"` (in Ruby string notation). The application takes the newline character literally and continues writing the filename on a new line. That's why it looks so strange!

You already know a way to fix it: call [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp) to get rid of the trailing newline (the separator). See the line in your code that contains `Dir.chdir` for an example.